# Push a detail view from mapView with a Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, mkmapview, pushviewcontroller

I have a tabbed application with one of the tabs being a map view. The user places a pin in a location and in the annotation callout there is a disclosure button. I want this button to push to a detail view with more specific details about the annotation. I have searched for related questions but none of them seem to have the same problem with it as I do. When the disclosure button is clicked, the application crashes with the exception: 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MapView tableView]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8434360'

This is where I attempt to push the detail view controller. The log statement returns a navigation controller so it is not an issue of sending a message to nil.

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
```

{

```
DetailViewController *dvc = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];
NSLog(@"%@", [self navigationController]);
[[SpotsStore defaultStore] setSelectedSpot:[view annotation]];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:dvc animated:YES];
```

}

I instantiated the navigation controller in the app delegate:

```
UINavigationController *mapnc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mv];
[mapnc setNavigationBarHidden:NO];
[[mapnc tabBarItem] setTitle:@"Map"];
[[mapnc tabBarItem] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mapicon.png"]];
[tbc setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:nc,mapnc, nil]];
// nc is a different navigation controller I instantiated earlier.
[[self window] setRootViewController:tbc];
```

I would really like any help with this, or just send me in the right direction. I could not find anything about the navigation controller sending the method tableView. Or why it doesn't work in this case.

Comment: The exception says "MapView" and not "MKMapView" so do you have a custom class named "MapView"?  Have you identified the _exact_ line that causes that exception (step through the code line-by-line in the debugger)?  Could it be something in setSelectedSpot?  Maybe the exception happens in the viewDidLoad of DetailViewController which gets called when it is pushed.

Comment: Yea I have a ViewController class named Map View  that contains the MKMapView. The exact line that causes the exception is pushing the detail view. The detail view works because with the tab view controller I also have a tableView with all the annotation objects and the detail view of those works and is the same detail view as I am trying to push from the map.

Answer (score 0):

I would stongly recommend using storyboards. Create a tabbarcontroller. Create a navigationcontroller with 2 viewcontrollers: the first is the map iewcontroller, the second is the detailviewcontroller. Ste this navigationcontroller to be one of the tabbarcontrollers viewcontrollers.
In your calloutaccessorytapped method call performSegue with the identifier that you defined in the storyboatd.

Comment: Okay I suppose I will have to try using storyboards instead. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. It was a piece of code in my detail view viewWillAppear method in which i reloaded the tableView. Thanks for your help though!